# Installshield patch issue for individual feature upgrade

Tags: installshield

we have a project , the porject contains three features and each feature contains its separate component files. we have also created patches for this install project. but have strange issues. 
The three features can be installed individually in several machines, we can say we have A,B.C three features. in machine 1, i have installed feature B only, and applyed patch1, 2 ,3 . but when i uninstall patch3, it will bring other component files in . just like it installed other features. Check the install dir it installed other features. almost every file from other features. How could it happen?  do anyone have a fix on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should supply a bit more detail. When you uninstall a patch it will restore the previous versions of the files. Is that what "bring other component files in" means? Or is it doing a repair of the entire product?

Comment: No, Phil, for example, when i installed only feature A in machine A, and feature A contains 3 files, and then i applied the patch on Machine A, and then uninstall the patch, it will bring feature B into machine A. which i don't expected this to happen.

Comment: Forgot to update here. i got it finally, it turns out that our product has some component that associated to two features. after re-structured the component association, issue is gone.   hope can help others who has this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reanalysis my project, i re-structured the feature and pick the common component into a separate feature, and that resolved the issue.